# Asp.net Identity Core With Web Api Core 2.0.

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I been going back and forth trying to figure out how to do authentication in my application. My original plan was to use Identity Sever 4 with Identity Core.

However I just can't figure out a easy way to manage and store all the roles/claims for a multiple application plus a few other issues.

I am now thinking it is just going to take too much time to get Identity Server 4 running that I might have it all great but no website lol.

Now I am thinking of just forgetting SSO for now and using Identity Core alone, which would be part of my application api.

I seen many tutorials on securing a core web api and identity core as an asp.net mvc core application but never together.

Is my understanding right, I would insert the Identity Core tables into my application api database, make some end points like "login, register" that could be make in each of my ui applications.

When a user comes to login they hit that end point, then they receive a JWT Bearer authorization token back that is then sent along for future requests.

Does Identity Core have a way to revoke these later?

Comment: If you use reference tokens, yes, these can be revoked. If you use self contained JWT then no you'll have to rely on short, but not annoying, expiry times. http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/reference_tokens.html Do the quick starts not help? http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/6_aspnet_identity.html not really sure what you're asking? "Where's best to start securing my web application?" Idsrv looks daunting but setting it up is very fast.

Comment: Maybe this [blog post](https://wildermuth.com/2017/08/19/Two-AuthorizationSchemes-in-ASP-NET-Core-2) will help.  Can you clarify what in particular you need help with?

Comment: @Mardoxx - The quick starts have helped but they don't answer the question on how to manage roles, yes if you use Identity Server Core then you can store the roles in there but what happens if you got 10 sites, How do you make roles for each site and make sure each user gets the right role for each site.

Comment: @MarkG - I am trying to understand how to use Asp.net Core Identity to secure my web api.

Comment: It seems like you're looking for multi-tenancy. That isn't supported OOTB but Identity is extensible, see this [blog post](https://www.scottbrady91.com/ASPNET-Identity/Quick-and-Easy-ASPNET-Identity-Multitenancy).  It would need to be adapted to ASP.NET Core though.

Comment: Regular JWT can not be revoked. They have expiration time. Refresh token may be the thing that you are imaginating as part of it can be revoked.